# Head Miscellaneous Scripts section

Tags: magento-1, configuration, admin-panel, system-config

I have a very strange problem.

I need to add some common script to my website, and I use **Miscellaneous Scripts** for that on

> system > configuration > design > html head

everything worked fine, but suddenly after one time I **saved my changes**, the section of Miscellaneous Scripts disappear, and I can't see it anymore.
the scripts still being included in the site.
Does anyone know anything about it?

Comment: What the version of Magento do you use?

Comment: @VadymKalin version 1.9.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, it seems that the script I added was too long, and that the reason magento didn't show it. at the end I change it in the db directly (via phpMyAdmin). I found the field using this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241971/magento-miscellaneous-scripts-in-header-config-retrieval, and change it. after the script became short, magento return to show it in the admin panel...

Answer (score 0):

Check if the files are actually found on the server. Also empty your cache from 
Magento eventhough you have turned the cache off.

I've your using Chrome try the following key command: ctrl + shift + R. This empties the cache of your browser.